# Simulating ENTER keypress in bash script

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu

I've created a really simple bash script that runs a few commands.
one of these commands needs user input during runtime. i.e it asks the user "do you want to blah blah blah?", I want to simply send an enter keypress to this so that the script will be completely automated.

I won't have to wait for the input or anything during runtime, its enough to just send the keypress and the input buffer will handle the rest.

Comment: If the tool you are trying to automate is `apt-get`, the proper solution is to preseed the debconf database with your preferred values; then it won't ask you.

Comment: You could use printf instead of echo : printf "hello\n"

Answer (score 180, accepted):

```
echo -ne '\n' | <yourfinecommandhere>
```

or taking advantage of the implicit newline that echo generates (thanks Marcin)

```
echo | <yourfinecommandhere>
```

Comment: if you feed this output to `xxd` you get `5c6e` hex, which is a literal `\n`.  if you do just `echo | xxd`  you actually end up with a hex of `0a`.  So I guess use whichever your program needs.

Comment: @Marcin, I am surprised, I get `0a0a` which is still not as intended, adding an `-n` suppreses the implicit newline. But your are of course right, a plain `echo | ...` works fine here. Will update my answer.

Comment: Heh, it didn't look quite right to me, so I had to feed it through xxd.  It's by far the simplest yet efficient method of seeing exactly what commands output.  Gotta love stupid Unix tricks.

Comment: @Marcin, still, why do you get `5c6e`? Did you omit the `-e` or does your shell or `echo` not treat that option?

Comment: i get: 
`echo  -ne "\n" | xxd 
0000000: 0a` 
and
`echo  -n "\n" | xxd 
0000000: 5c6e` 
and 
`echo  "\n" | xxd 
0000000: 5c6e 0a` 
I have not seen any difference between single and double quotes.
My shell is just a regular bash, is there settings that would regulate behavior of such basic functionality?

Comment: @Marcin, your last findings are all as I would expect. Also, back-slash is only treated special in double-quotes for dollar, back-tick, double-quote, backslash and newline according to `man bash`, so that's fine too. I was puzzled by your original comment stating that `echo -e '\n' | xxd` would output `0000000: 5c6e`. Can you still reproduce this?

Comment: Is it portable on OSX?

Comment: The behaviour of `echo` is highly dependent on your shell and system, it varies quite a lot actually (which explains some of the comments). The only thing that is guaranteed to work is `echo "string without escape characters"`. There is no need to add this part to your answer, as `echo | cmd` is exactly the same. I recommend you edit it out (if you *do* want an explicit newline echo, then `printf '\n'` is the portable way to do that).

Comment: @TilmanVogel How to chain this? I would like to press multiple enters after running `mycommand`.

Comment: @Sunlight What do you mean by "after running"? If you want to feed multiple enters to the same program, you can easily do `echo -ne '\n\n\n' | <mycommand>` to feed it three enters. If you need an indefinite number of enters, use `yes` as suggested by some of the other answers.

Answer (score 55):

You might find the `yes` command useful.

See `man yes`

Comment: `yes` I do find it useful.

Comment: This simulates pressing "y" repeatedly rather than the Enter key. While this is probably what you want to yes/no questions, it won't work for anything that doesn't expect a "y".

Comment: @BurhanAli: you can change what `yes` sends as its output. Read the man page.

Comment: can I send yes mutiple times for a script that expects default values [value] {enter}

Comment: This only works for things like yum. Where that string is expected.

Answer (score 54):

You can just use [yes](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/yes.1.html).

```
# yes "" | someCommand
```

Answer (score 25):

Here is sample usage using `expect`:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
set timeout 360
spawn my_command # Replace with your command.
expect "Do you want to continue?" { send "\r" }
```

Check: [`man expect`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/expect) for further information.

Comment: especially helpful if multiple enter keypresses need to be sent

Comment: This is the best way, specially for things like phars where different stdout and stdin strings are sent.

Comment: Also remember to just enter my_command arg if you have an argument.

Comment: It always says: invalid command name "my_command", even when command is simple like "ls".

Answer (score 11):

You could make use of [expect](http://linux.die.net/man/1/expect) (*man expect* comes with examples).

Answer (score 3):

I know this is old but hopefully, someone will find this helpful.

If you have multiple user inputs that need to be handled you can use [process substitution](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html) and use echo as a 'file' for cat with whatever is needed to handle the first input like this:

```
# cat ignores stdin if it has a file to look at
cat <(echo "selection here") | command
```

and then you can handle subsequent inputs by piping the [yes](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/yes.1.html) command with the answer:

```
cat <(echo "selection here") | yes 'y' | command
```

Comment: just what I needed thanks. I'm generating 12 different NestJs modules and each command has two prompts.

Answer (score 2):

you could use xdotool to simulate a "enter":

```
xdotool key 'Return' | commandhere
```

or you can make it sleep then enter a command:

```
sleep 0.5; xdotool key 'Return' | commandhere
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I needed. I put it in a for loop because i needed to spam it