# How to simulate pressing enter in a bash script

Tags: bash

This is my first bash script. I want to run a script five times, the script is located in the same folder that this script will be located. My problem is that I cannot find how to simulate pressing enter. Since this script needs to load the data first it takes two seconds after running it, then it prompts you to press enter. I want to simulate doing this five times. How can I do the 3 second delay and press enter after? Any other problems with my script?

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in {1..5}
do
   ./clientScript.py
   #Press enter after a 3 second pause
done
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Simulating ENTER keypress in bash script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6264596/simulating-enter-keypress-in-bash-script)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this should work:

```
echo | ./clientScript.py
```

it simply outputs a `\n` to the stdin of your python script.

Comment: This doesn't pause and doesn't have to -- the application will just spend a few seconds loading and will read the input when it finds the time.

Comment: To send 3 newlines: `{ echo; echo; echo; } | program` or `printf "\n\n\n" | program`