# Making the script issue "enter" after executing command in shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I am trying to write a shell script to execute various commands automatically for my app. There is one scenario where am blocked.

For example there is a command which requires a yes/no command line input to complete execution. For this I have used `echo "yes" | <commmand>` and it works fine.

Similarly I have a scenario where I have to press an **enter** to get the command prompt back after executing a command, to proceed. Please give me some hints on how to make my script do this automatically.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6264596/simulating-enter-keypress-in-bash-script

Comment: If the number of interactive actions is high, you could use [expect](http://www.tcl.tk/man/expect5.31/expect.1.html) from your bash script.

Comment: hints: `cat <<EOF | script` or `expect`

Comment: Check the command man pages, because many commands can have their interactive behaviour disabled. For example 'yum -y'.