# Shell: write a script that gets executed on stdin wait

Tags: bash, shell

I have this command `command` that at some point, returns: `Press Enter to continue`.

I would like to write a script that calls `command`, reads the so-far command output, does something with it when `Press Enter to continue` arrives, and simulates an enter key-press when this is done.

Any chance I can achieve that? :-D

Something like:

```
myscript | command > output
```

with `myscript`

```
#!/bin/bash

cp output output2 # output2 should only contain the output until Press Enter to continue
echo -ne '\n'
```

except it doesn't work! :-)

Comment: `echo -ne '\n'` is amazingly bizarre. That is effectively the same as `echo` only less portable and more to type and read.

Comment: That said what about this attempt doesn't work? Does it not confirm the prompt? Is the prompt reading from standard input or from the tty directly? I also didn't understand the bit about the output file. You want to copy the output file right before "hitting enter"?

Comment: look for a tutorial on the `expect` program? (AND it's unclear what you mean by "I have this command `> command`". Is the `>` the cmd prompt? If so, you don't need to include it. If meant to indicate file redirection, you're creating, or wiping out the file `command` in your current dir). Please try to make a small, reproducible test case we can follow along with. Good luck.

Comment: `echo -ne '\n'` comes from [there](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6264596/simulating-enter-keypress-in-bash-script). `cp output output2` is only an example, I'll actually `sed` something and create another file out of it. Yes `>` was the command prompt, I removed it! My example actually works correctly, except it does't receive the input right before `Press Enter to continue`, which *is* the one I need... I tried to add some `sleep`, without success...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally you should use `expect` command to achieve that, example code:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
set timeout 600
spawn command
expect "Press Enter to continue" { send "\r" }
```

<sup>Note: Replace `command` with your command.</sup>

then save it into the script, make it executable and run it.

Check: [`man expect`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/expect) for further information.

On OS X install via: `brew install expect`.