# Send keystroke to Dockerfile, Ubuntu

Tags: bash, ubuntu, docker, command

I'm creating Dockerfile script and it has a command line that executes a program and requires user input **1** from keyboard as selected option to go to further steps.

[**Xdotool**](http://www.semicomplete.com/projects/xdotool/), [**man yes**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6264596/simulating-enter-keypress-in-bash-script) or [**expect**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6264596/simulating-enter-keypress-in-bash-script) cannot help in this situation.

Update source-code:

First off, download and extract RevoMath library, navigate to RevoMath folder then execute the install script.

```
...
RUN wget -q https://mran.microsoft.com/install/mro/3.2.4/RevoMath-3.2.4.tar.gz
RUN tar -xzf RevoMath-3.2.4.tar.gz
RUN cd RevoMath/
RUN ./RevoMath.sh
...
```

Install script has some select options as follow:

```
echo "1. Install MKL"
echo "2. Uninstall MKL"
echo "3. Exit utility"
```

We need to enter **1** from keyboard to install. How can we do it via Docker command?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Is it possible for you to share the program you want to execute (so we can try to reproduce / find a solution)?

Comment: @ChristopheSchmitz: Hi, I've updated my post. Thanks

Comment: Build your image before entering 1, run it, enter 1, `docker commit -t myimage` , create a new Dockerfile starting with `FROM myimage` and go on

Comment: @TimUgent could you check my answer?

Answer (score 2):

If I correctly understand you, you would like to add `echo 1 |` before `./RevoMath.sh` in your **Dockerfile**:

```
...
RUN cd RevoMath/ && echo 1 | ./RevoMath.sh
...
```

BTW: In your example this lines will not work as you expected:

```
RUN cd RevoMath/
RUN ./RevoMath.sh
```

Because each `RUN` is an independent execution.
You should use `&&` if you want to execute RevoMath.sh script from specific folder (see my example in the beginning)

Comment: This helped me with another script where I needed to press "Y" on the keyboard to allow for a package to install. Thank you very much for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use redirect from standard input.

For example install.sh required some input(s) from user at execution time.
Suppose you need to enter **1** as a response to first interaction(questions) and
then you have another response as **y** for further interaction then it's good to use redirect from stdin.

```
$#>install.sh <EOF
$#>1
$#>y
$#>EOF
```

This way whenever script is waiting for inputs it will answer as 1 for the first question and y for the second question.