# How do you send the ENTER keypressed to ansible's expect?

Tags: ansible, pexpect

I want to write playbook which installs an application using their installer. I am using ansible's `expect` module to do this. At the beginning of the installation, it asks to press `ENTER` to continue with the installation. How do I send expect the `ENTER` keypress ?

Comment: have you tried `child.sendline()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There’s a linux command called `yes` which "outputs an affirmative response, or a user-defined string of text".

I didn't check it, but you could try using:

```
- shell: yes '' | your command goes here
```

Have a look at [simulation keypress in bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6264596/simulating-enter-keypress-in-bash-script).

Taken [from documentation](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/expect_module.html):

> If you want to run a command through the shell (say you are using `<`, `>`, `|`, etc), you must specify a shell in the command such as `/bin/bash -c "/path/to/something | grep else"`

Therefore, you can try `/bin/bash -c "echo"` or something similar as a response, something like:

```
responses:
  press_enter: /bin/bash -c "echo"
```

Comment: I want to use this with the `expect` module not the `shell` module.

Comment: Have a look at [documentation](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/expect_module.html), you can try `echo` as answer

Comment: @LowKianSeong, I've altered answer a little. If you solved your problem and you have something to add - improve it! I might've mistaken with syntax