# Simulate ENTER key in bash here-document

Tags: bash, enter, heredoc

Is there a way to simulate ENTER key in a bash script imputing values to a code through a here-document (EOF). Readily possible in bash, see [question 6264596](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6264596/simulating-enter-keypress-in-bash-script).

Pseudo code:

```
 #!/bin/bash
 code_executable << EOF
 value1
 value2 
 EOF
```

`value2` needs to be followed by a carriage return, ie ENTER when executing from a shell.

Thanks guys.

Simulation of executable running on a terminal:

```
  $./code_executable
  >Do you want to continue? yes or no
  User: y
  >Enter number:
  User: 314
```

If User doesn't press ENTER on keyboard after entering 314, executable hangs/halts there and waits.

**Edit**: see exceptions in stdin buffering that prevent the EOF from passing arguments to an executable as illustrated by @that other guy answer below.

Comment: Do you just want a blank line after `value2` but before `EOF`?

Comment: @chepner: I'm not sure. I added a literal blank line between `value2` and EOF and still not solved, executable can't get `value2`.

Comment: Maybe there's a bug in the executable? With the script as shown in the question, the executable should see a line `"value1\n"`, followed by a line `"value2\n"`, followed by an end-of-file condition. Adding a blank line between `value2` and `EOF` should give the executable an additional line `"\n"`. What happens when you run the executable by itself and give it input from the keyboard?

Comment: @ Keith Thompson: no bug in executable. `value1` is fetched without waiting for carriage return, while `value2` is not. This what happens when run from a terminal: ask for `value1` then upon "typing" the latter immediately follows instruction to impute `value2` which stays there until typing ENTER.

Comment: I didn't down-vote, but your question lacks clarity. Also, please add clarifications _directly to your question_, not in comments.
I couldn't make sense of you most recent comment describing the interactive behavior.

Comment: Mayhaps `code_exacutable` is `FTP.EXE` or similar? Programs that read from /dev/tty cannot be redirected this way.

Comment: Your example does not show what happens after pressing 314 and pressing enter.  Do you drop back to the prompt or do you have to type QUIT, EXIT or Ctrl-C to exit code_executable?  What is code_executable anyway, homegrown or a known program? Showing an actual running of it with input and output from start to finish indicating exactly what you had to type may help.

Comment: @Gary: when pressing `314`, now-famous executable (homegrown C++) finishes its job on the terminal. No need to further intervention from user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sup>* See [that other guy's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38727755/45375) for useful background information and tips for what the actual problem may be.

* This answer assumes a well-behaved program that reads prompt inputs from stdin - as it turns out, not using such a program was precisely the OP's problem: their program behaves *differently* when inputs are provided via stdin as opposed to by interactive typing.</sup>

Let's simulate your executable with the following script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

printf ">Do you want to continue? (y)es or (n)o: "
read -r -n 1  confirm  # NOTE: A *single* keypress terminates input here.
printf "\nUser: $confirm\n"

printf ">Enter number: "
read -r  number
printf "User: $number\n"
```

To provide the sample input in your question to this script via stdin, using a [here-document](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/HereDocument):

```
./code_executable <<EOF
y314
EOF
```

**Note the absence of a newline between `y` and `314` to account for the fact that the 1st prompt does *not* require an ENTER keypress** to commit the input - only a single character.

**With a here-document, the overall input invariably ends in a newline (`\n`)**, which **acts as if Enter had been pressed** (as explained in [that other guy's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38727755/45375)) and therefore submits the input to the 2nd prompt.

Additional prompt inputs can simply be added before the closing `EOF` delimiter, with each additional input that requires Enter to submit on its own line.

```
./code_executable <<EOF
y314
next input
...
EOF
```

Comment: @ mklement0: thanks so much for your suggestion. I tested your solution, to unfortunately no avail. I need to pass several args to executable, hence the use of `EOF`...but I am open to other suggestions.

Comment: @slkuser: I've removed the here-string alternative (`<<<`) to avoid confusion. You can simply add additional inputs (that's what I assume you meant by args) to the here-document - please see my update.

Comment: @ mklement0: actually using `y314` instead of `314` did not solve the problem. There are no further user inputs after (but before) this argument that requires press enter.

Comment: The only plausible explanation at this point is that your C++ program doesn't (consistently) read from _stdin_, and perhaps reads prompt inputs from the _terminal_ directly (as has already been suggested). Without knowing what your program truly does, we can't help you. My sample script that simulates your program is well-behaved in terms of reading from stdin, and, as you can tell, it works.

Answer (score 4):

Enter is normally represented by a linefeed, not a carriage return. Programs are frequently confused by carriage returns, so terminals will automatically translate them to line feeds.

You can see this in a hex dump:

```
holen@vidarh2 11:14 ~ $ hexdump -C
(press enter several times, end with ctrl+d)
00000000  0a 0a 0a 0a                                       |....|
           ^----------- line feeds
```

If you look at your script, you can see that it already adds one after value2 and your trailing space:

```
$ cat yourscript 
#!/bin/bash
hexdump -C << EOF
value1
value2 
EOF

$ ./yourscript 
00000000  76 61 6c 75 65 31 0a 76  61 6c 75 65 32 20 0a     |value1.value2 .|
                                        line feed ----^
```

Here's an example of this working:

```
$ ./ex1
Continue?
yes
Number?
123
You wrote: 123

$ ./ex1 << EOF
> yes
> 123
> EOF
Continue?
Number?
You wrote: 123
```

Here's an example of this failing due to a buffering bug in the program, even though the program appears to work exactly the same when run interactively but receives wrong input:

```
$ ./ex2
Continue?
yes
Number?
123
You wrote: 123

$ ./ex2 << EOF
yes
123
EOF

Continue?
Number?
You wrote: yes
```

Here's a third example of a different kind of buffering bug, where the program works the same interactively but appears to receive no input from a here document:

```
$ ./ex3
Continue?
yes
Number?
123
You wrote: 123

$ ./ex3 << EOF
yes
123
EOF
Continue?
Number?
You wrote:
```

They read lines with `fscanf(stdin, ..)`, `fdopen(0, "r"); fscanf(file, ...` and `read(0, buffer, 1024)` respectively. Only the first one is correct.

Comment: @ other guy: please see my comment above. Thanks for the explanation. However, it does not suggest a resolution.

Comment: Yes it does, just not to your implicit follow-up "why isn't my secret program interpreting the enter key press that is correctly added?"

Comment: @ : I don't think I understand your comment. I clarified the question with a simulated execution from the terminal.

Comment: @slkuser Still sounds like a bug in your program. I added an example of three programs that work identically when running interactively, where only one works with a here document. Non-interactive programs have different buffering and timing behavior that buggy programs may rely on.

Comment: @ other guy: thanks so much for the detailed debugging. The executable in question uses non of the stdin functions you pointed to..rather a custom defined one to do the read-line. And indeed it behaves like the non-working situations.

Comment: @slkuser: I suggest you (a) add a big disclaimer at the top of your question that your specific problem cannot be solved as presented, because the problem lies _elsewhere_, (b) _accept this answer_, because it answers the question _as asked_ (and additionally provides great pointers as to what the true problem may be), (c) open a new question, in which you ask why your custom-defined read-line function doesn't works as expected.

Comment: @ other guy. This question is non-trivial as you demonstrated and it is answered by @ mklement0 below as far as EOF+RETURN is concerned. I removed the edit note to reflect that it has been answered.