# Send 'Enter' key to a computer with shell script

Tags: bios

I want to send an 'Enter' key to my workstation with a shell script. 
The problem is the following: When my workstation turning on, it writes a hardware problem (901-chassis fan not detected) to the screen and it sais press ENTER. When I would like to work at home, I can wake up my computer with a script which runs by the server, but I can't press Enter. Is there any way to send 'Enter' with a script? I can use the my workstation mac address.
(I have no permission to solve the hardware problem in my company)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6264596/simulating-enter-keypress-in-bash-script

Comment: @MarounMaroun Shell wouldn't even be started.

Comment: You can check the BIOS setting to see if there is a setting to disable this warning; there often is. Either way, this isn't something you can program since it's before any OS has started (and thus not really a programming question).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you can't send an ENTER key until shell is started.