# Simulating Enter in bash function

Tags: linux, bash, macos

I've looked around and haven't found an answer to this.  This is not to be mistaken with questions about [bash scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6264596/simulating-enter-keypress-in-bash-script).

I'm looking to automate an installation for a composer package. There are several requested inputs during the installation process - though they have acceptable defaults.  I would like to output a  through multiple times to accept the defaults with a bash function.

```
sage() {
  if (( $# == 0 ))
  then
    composer create-project roots/sage $1
  else
    composer create-project roots/sage
  fi

  echo "\r";
  echo "\r";
  echo "\r";
  echo "\r";
  echo "\r";
  echo "\r";
  echo "https://localhost/$1";
}
```

This doesn't do what I want, and still focuses inside the first input box.  How do I need to change this so the carriage return is inserted after the package has installed?

Trying Expect:

- Does it have to be verbatim what the input question is or is it just
  a regex?

Edit:

So far, I've tried

```
expect "Theme Name [Sage Starter Theme]" { send "\r" }
------------------------------------------------
expect "Theme Name [Sage Starter Theme]" 
send "\r"
```

Comment: "expect" is what you want to use.

Comment: If I understand, you want the things you echo to be passed as input to the composer command?

Comment: Then perhaps you need to look at the bash `<<<` pipe operator.

Comment: `<<<` is a less-capable, less portable, shorthand version of heredoc support. If you're going to learn only one thing, should probably make it the more capable thing.

Comment: @DanielFoust, if the more generalized questions about scripts' answers work just as well with functions, your question is still duplicative of them; there's no point to a narrower question unless the other ones didn't get answers that successfully apply. Take all the `echo`s out of your function, and feed that input on a heredoc: `sage <<EOF`, follow with a bunch of newlines and `http://localhost:$1`, then `EOF`, and there you are.

Comment: ...that said, a *well-written* installer (and there are many of those -- you should check whether `composer` is one, and push a patch upstream if not) will provide a better way to override inputs -- a separate named environment variables per potential prompt, a config file, etc; assuming that the same questions will be asked in the same order between releases makes for needlessly fragile code.