# add answer to first commands question in shell script

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu, sh

I have a first command in .sh file i.e.

```
cassandras3 backup --keyspace jl_powereasy_kespace --bucket database-backup-rds
```

This command asks a question when we run i.e.

```
Your cassandra data directory [/var/lib/cassandra/data]:
```

how can I confirm this answer in shell script. I need to press enter for this confirmation automatically.

```
root@ip-172-31-2-150:/home/ubuntu# /bin/bash /var/cassandra_backupV1.sh
Your cassandra data directory [/var/lib/cassandra/data]:
```

Comment: `echo | cassandras3 ...`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6264618/6835535), you can try running the command with echo as follows

```
echo -ne '\n' | cassandras3 backup --keyspace jl_powereasy_kespace --bucket database-backup-rds
```

or simply

```
echo | cassandras3 backup --keyspace jl_powereasy_kespace --bucket database-backup-rds
```