# Bash: pass keyboard input inside for loop

Tags: bash

I am writing a simple code for gcloud. In my script, I want to get a list of all projects on an account and for each of them call a gcloud command that requires user input which I want to emulate in my bash script.

```
projects_list=$(gcloud projects list)

for n in $projects_list
do
    gcloud projects dosomething $n
done
```

Every time I call gcloud projects dosomething, it asks "Do you want to continue (Y/n)?" and waits for an input from user. How do I automate this and make script emulate pressing Y?

Comment: Try: `export CLOUDSDK_CORE_DISABLE_PROMPTS=1`

Comment: i think that this question can help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6264596/simulating-enter-keypress-in-bash-script

Comment: @Ferdinando Thanks! The second answer in that thread works:
`yes | gcloud projects delete` @WilliamPursell I guess that could work too. I'll just need to change it back to 0 after loop because that is the only part of the script where I want to skip prompt